# How to group rows based on a condition in a dataframe with python pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, rows

I want to change the range of ages (EDAT) so that the  two first range of ages now 0 to 9 and 10 to 19 stay as a single age range from 0 to 19 without changing the other values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATA': ['2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10'], 'EDAT':['0 a 9',
 '10 a 19',
 '10 a 19',
 '20 a 29',
 '20 a 29',
 '20 a 29',
 '30 a 39',
 '30 a 39',
 '30 a 39',
 '30 a 39'], 'ESDEVENIMENT': ['Cas',
 'Cas',
 'Cas',
 'Cas',
 'Cas',
 'Hospitalització',
 'Cas',
 'Cas',
 'Cas',
 'Hospitalització'], 'PAUTA': ['No iniciada',
 'Completa',
 'No iniciada',
 'Completa',
 'No iniciada',
 'No iniciada',
 'Completa',
 'No iniciada',
 'Parcial',
 'No iniciada'], 'RECOMPTE': [6,
 5,
 6,
 3,
 4,
 2,
 7,
 10,
 1,
 2]})
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Take a while to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Working with text data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html).

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['EDAT'] = df['EDAT'].str.replace(r'(0 a 9|10 a 19)', '0 a 19', regex=True)
print(df)

# Output
         DATA     EDAT     ESDEVENIMENT        PAUTA  RECOMPTE
0  2021-10-10   0 a 19              Cas  No iniciada         6
1  2021-10-10   0 a 19              Cas     Completa         5
2  2021-10-10   0 a 19              Cas  No iniciada         6
3  2021-10-10  20 a 29              Cas     Completa         3
4  2021-10-10  20 a 29              Cas  No iniciada         4
5  2021-10-10  20 a 29  Hospitalització  No iniciada         2
6  2021-10-10  30 a 39              Cas     Completa         7
7  2021-10-10  30 a 39              Cas  No iniciada        10
8  2021-10-10  30 a 39              Cas      Parcial         1
9  2021-10-10  30 a 39  Hospitalització  No iniciada         2
```

Comment: Finally I have used:  df['EDAT'] = df['EDAT'].str.replace(r'(0 a 9|10 a 19)', '0 a 19', regex=True) and next df_unisex_date_age_prov = df_unisex_targ_date.groupby([ "DATA", "EDAT", "ESDEVENIMENT", "PAUTA"])[["RECOMPTE"]].sum()  getting the sum of the fields,

Answer (score 0):

You can use .loc for assignment.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATA': ['2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10',
 '2021-10-10'], 'EDAT':['0 a 9',
 '10 a 19',
 '10 a 19',
 '20 a 29',
 '20 a 29',
 '20 a 29',
 '30 a 39',
 '30 a 39',
 '30 a 39',
 '30 a 39'], 'ESDEVENIMENT': ['Cas',
 'Cas',
 'Cas',
 'Cas',
 'Cas',
 'Hospitalització',
 'Cas',
 'Cas',
 'Cas',
 'Hospitalització'], 'PAUTA': ['No iniciada',
 'Completa',
 'No iniciada',
 'Completa',
 'No iniciada',
 'No iniciada',
 'Completa',
 'No iniciada',
 'Parcial',
 'No iniciada'], 'RECOMPTE': [6,
 5,
 6,
 3,
 4,
 2,
 7,
 10,
 1,
 2]})

df.loc[0:2, 'EDAT'] = '0 a 19'

print(df) 


    DATA        EDAT    ESDEVENIMENT    PAUTA       RECOMPTE
0   2021-10-10  0 a 19  Cas             No iniciada 6
1   2021-10-10  0 a 19  Cas             Completa    5
2   2021-10-10  0 a 19  Cas             No iniciada 6
3   2021-10-10  20 a 29 Cas             Completa    3
4   2021-10-10  20 a 29 Cas             No iniciada 4
5   2021-10-10  20 a 29 Hospitalització No iniciada 2
6   2021-10-10  30 a 39 Cas             Completa    7
7   2021-10-10  30 a 39 Cas             No iniciada 10
8   2021-10-10  30 a 39 Cas             Parcial     1
9   2021-10-10  30 a 39 Hospitalització No iniciada 2
```